# How can i use handlebars data in front end js variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm passing an object array to handlebars.
i'm retrieving it on front end like this

`{{this.coment}}`

The object contains this:

```
`{
    _id: "5c527707e28b4fac758cc674",
    sectionId: "2",
    comments: [
      {
        replies: [],
        authorAvatarUrl:
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q&#x3D;tbn:ANd9GcRDW3D0Emu0_gpP-tAEGPjW88zSabvpdICv6BaoNLArqY3xB4NA",
        authorName: "Jesus Zuñiga Vega",
        authorId: "1",
        authorUrl: "",
        comment: "Test",
        id: "72845"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5c5279f2e28b4fac758cc761",
    sectionId: "3",
    comments: [
      {
        replies: [],
        authorAvatarUrl:
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q&#x3D;tbn:ANd9GcRDW3D0Emu0_gpP-tAEGPjW88zSabvpdICv6BaoNLArqY3xB4NA",
        authorName: "Jesus Zuñiga Vega",
        authorId: "1",
        authorUrl: "",
        comment: "Test2",
        id: "37940"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5c527ce2e28b4fac758cc887",
    sectionId: "1",
    comments: [
      {
        replies: [],
        authorAvatarUrl:
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q&#x3D;tbn:ANd9GcRDW3D0Emu0_gpP-tAEGPjW88zSabvpdICv6BaoNLArqY3xB4NA",
        authorName: "Jesus Zuñiga Vega",
        authorId: "1",
        authorUrl: "",
        comment: "Hello",
        id: "77251"
      }
    ]
  }`
```

Note that it is missing the "[ ]" of the array

i want to know if it is possible to put the data in a js variable to use it in front end like this:

```
var existingComments = [
  {
    _id: "5c527707e28b4fac758cc674",
    sectionId: "2",
    comments: [
      {
        replies: [],
        authorAvatarUrl:
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q&#x3D;tbn:ANd9GcRDW3D0Emu0_gpP-tAEGPjW88zSabvpdICv6BaoNLArqY3xB4NA",
        authorName: "Jesus Zuñiga Vega",
        authorId: "1",
        authorUrl: "",
        comment: "Test",
        id: "72845"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5c5279f2e28b4fac758cc761",
    sectionId: "3",
    comments: [
      {
        replies: [],
        authorAvatarUrl:
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q&#x3D;tbn:ANd9GcRDW3D0Emu0_gpP-tAEGPjW88zSabvpdICv6BaoNLArqY3xB4NA",
        authorName: "Jesus Zuñiga Vega",
        authorId: "1",
        authorUrl: "",
        comment: "Test2",
        id: "37940"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5c527ce2e28b4fac758cc887",
    sectionId: "1",
    comments: [
      {
        replies: [],
        authorAvatarUrl:
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q&#x3D;tbn:ANd9GcRDW3D0Emu0_gpP-tAEGPjW88zSabvpdICv6BaoNLArqY3xB4NA",
        authorName: "Jesus Zuñiga Vega",
        authorId: "1",
        authorUrl: "",
        comment: "Hello",
        id: "77251"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Any help will be much aprecciated thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you want to assign this.coment value to a variable in front end ?

Comment: yeah, so i can use it to show the array in comments

Comment: I answered below have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by creating helpers in the route file like this

```
handlebars = handlebars.create({
 helpers: {
  assign:function (varName, varValue, options) {
        if (!options.data.root) {
            options.data.root = {};
        }
        options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
    }
 }
})
```

And then in front end you can initialize or assign value to a variable like this

```
{{assign 'existingComments' this.coment}}
```

And then in order to access can use

```
{{@root.existingComments }}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is by generating a `script` tag.

```
<script type="application/javascript">var comment = {{{this.coment}}};</script>
```

Now, the variable should be available to use in your Javascript.  However, I do not prefer this approach since it is using a global variable.

Comment: it parses the variable like this
<script type="application/javascript">var comment = [{ _id: &#x27;5c527707e28b4fac758cc674&#x27
...
and throws an error

Comment: then, use var comment = {{{this.coment}}};